# Flink: TypeExtractor complains about protobuf class even though a ProtobufSerializer is registered for it

Tags: apache-flink

Using Flink 1.12.

My protobuf is

```
syntax = "proto3";
package flink.protobuf;
message TimestampedMessage {
    int64 timeMs = 1;
    string message = 2;
}
```

and tried to use it like so

```
        final var env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
        env.getConfig().registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(TimestampedMessage.class, ProtobufSerializer.class);
        env.fromCollection(new EventsIter(), TimestampedMessage.class)
        ...
```

But the logs show this

```
flink.protobuf.Test$TimestampedMessage does not contain a setter for field timeMs_
2021-08-12 06:38:19,940 INFO org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor Class class 
flink.protobuf.Test$TimestampedMessage cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are 
valid POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink
 documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is using the ProtobufSerializer despite the warning.